# Concatenating from table to string, sum amounts

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the Google Sheets table below:

```
       A             B            C        D
 1 category      subcategory    company  amount
 2 health care   diagnostics     AA       100
 3 health care   diagnostics     AB        50
 4 materials     mining          BA        75
 5 financials    banks           CA        30
 6 financials    insurers        CB        35
 7 financials    banks           CC        10
 8 financials    banks           CD        40
 9 financials    hedge fund      CE         5
10 health care   equipment       DA        50
```

I would like to list, per `subcategory`, the `companies` in it, and the `amount spent`:

```
      A              B              C
1 category       companies       amount
2 health care    AA AB DA          200     <--- 100 + 50 + 50
3 materials      BA                 75
4 financials     CA CB CC CD CE    120
```

Column A I will type myself / hardcode. But what formula in column `B` and `C` will give this result, depending on the value in `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E3:E, QUERY({QUERY({A:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col4)'amount'", 1), {"companies"; 
 TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A:D, C:C}, 
 "select max(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col5"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)))}}, 
 "select Col1,Col3,Col2", 1), {2,3}, 0)))
```

where E3:E are your hardcoded values

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm having such a difficult time understanding this solution. To break it down, would it be possible to have a separate formula for `companies` and `amount`? If it is more broken-down, I can better understand and adjust as I'm expanding my Google Sheet.

Comment: @Pr0no yes, see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhtBQpYE_9hyzPjVGF6vBY6QPEfjcyIUTlFOBkXlpw4/edit#gid=813334203

Comment: One last question please. For the "drag down" formulas, assuming that the `amount` for `company CE` is `0` instead of `5`. Is it possible to color that company name red (or in any other way make it distinctive, eg. surround by [ and ] or append an asteriks) in the concatenation in column `F` (in your above screenshot)? So for `Financials`, the listing would look sth like `CA CB CC CD (CE)`

Comment: you can use: `=JOIN(" ", FILTER(C$2:C, A$2:A=F4, D$2:D<>0), "("&FILTER(C$2:C, A$2:A=F4, D$2:D=0)&")")`

Comment: It throws an error `No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.` when dragging down, which I don't understand bc I checked all values in the formula and it should match: in `N5`, we're looking for `F5` (materials) in the same data range as in which we were looking for financials in `N4`. What is causing the error?

Comment: try like this: `=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IFERROR(FILTER(C$2:C, A$2:A=F5, D$2:D<>0)), IFERROR("("&FILTER(C$2:C, A$2:A=F5, D$2:D=0)&")"))`